Showing a certain rule defines a topology

Let $L_1, L_2, L_3, \ldots$ be a family (sequence) of parallel lines in the plane, and let $X$ be an infinite union of $L_n$. Let us call a subset $G$ of $X$ big if either $G = \varnothing$ or $L_n \setminus G$ is finite for every $n \ge n_0$ granted there's such an $n_0$. Is the family of all big subsets of $X$ a topology on $X$?

This given topology(?) looks like cofinite topology except $L_n \setminus G$ is kind of hard to make sense given that we are subtracting a set whose cardinality can be greater than one from a singleton set.
Would the following be enough to show the property that finite intersection of open sets is open, for example?
Let $G_1,\ldots G_n$ be open. Then:
$$ X \setminus \bigcap_{i=1}^n G_i  = \bigcup_{i=1}^n  (X \setminus G_i)$$
Since $G_i$ is open, $X \setminus G_i$ is finite and so the RHS of the equality above is finite meaning LHS is finite and so the finite intersection of $G_i$ is open.

But you don't know that $X\setminus G_i$ is finite. You know that for every sufficiently large $m$, $L_m\setminus G_i$ is always finite.

Would replacing $X$ with $L_n$ in the De Morgan equality above fix the problem?

Yes, but you have to verify this. First of all, don't forget about the case that some $G_i$ might be empty. (this is a trivial case, but should not be forgotten) In any other case, for each $i$ there is some index $m_i$ such that $L_m\setminus G_i$ is finite whenever $m\geq m_i$. Now find a corresponding index for the intersection.

Something like $\bigcup_{i=1, k = m}^n(L_k \setminus G_i)$?
